# How to multiply each column of matrix A by each row of matrix B and sum resulting matrices in Matlab?

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a problem which I hope can be easily solved.
A is a N*G matrix, B is N*G matrix. The goal is to get matrix C

[image]

which is equal to multiplying each column of transposed A by each row of B and summing resulting matrices; total number of such matrices before summing is N*N, their size is G*G
This can be easily done in MatLab with two *for*-loops:

```
N=5;
G=10;
A=rand(N,G);
B=rand(N,G);
C=zeros(G);
for n=1:1:N
    for m=1:1:N
        C=C+A(m,:)'*B(n,:);
    end
end
```

However, for large matrices it is quite slow.

So, my question is:
is there a more efficient way for calculating C matrix in Matlab?

Thank you

Comment: +1 for well expressed, worked question, and for self-contained code

Comment: @Bibek Subedi  For N=2;G=2;A=[1 2; 3 4];B=[5 6; 7 8]; my code returns C=[48 56;72 84] and A'*B=[26 30;38 44]

A'*B is equal to single-sum sum_{n} A_{ni}B_{nk}, and not to double-sum sum_{m,n} A_{mi}B_{nk} which I need

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you write it all out for two 3×3 matrices, you'll find that the operation basically equals this:

```
C = bsxfun(@times, sum(B), sum(A).');
```

Running each of the answers here for `N=50`, `G=100` and repeating each method 100 times:

```
Elapsed time is 13.839893 seconds. %// OP's original method
Elapsed time is 19.773445 seconds. %// Luis' method
Elapsed time is 0.306447 seconds.  %// Robert's method
Elapsed time is 0.005036 seconds.  %// Rody's method
```

(a factor of ≈ 4000 between the fastest and slowest method...)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked
Shame on me not seeing it on my own)

Comment: +1 Well thought! The [distributive property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) greatly reduces the number of operations in this case

Answer (score 3):

I think this should improve the performance significantly

```
C = zeros(G);
for n = 1:N
   C = C + sum(A,1)'*B(n,:);
end
```

You avoid one loop, and should also avoid the problems of running out of memory. According to my benchmarking, it's about 20 times faster than the approach with two loops. (Note, I had to benchmark in Octace since I don't have MATLAB on this PC).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) instead of the loops, and then [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) twice:

```
C = sum(sum(bsxfun(@times, permute(A, [2 3 1]), permute(B,[3 2 4 1])), 3), 4);
```

Comment: @Adiel As for `arrayfun` I agree. As for `bsxfun`, not so much

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've checked it and its works nice for small N and G. However for G=1000 and N=100 (which is yet smaller than my real matrices) I'm out of my system memory.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Yes, I applied the OP's description literally (multiply and then add). I didn't realize that adding first, as in your answer, saves a lot of memory and operations.